# Rider IDE UML generator like yFile in IntelliJ

Tags: uml, rider

I'm developing C# .Net Core 2.0 on Rider IDE.I cannot find a plugin which sketches UML diagram.I know a plugin called yFile that it exist in IntelliJ IDEA for Java.But seems not available for Rider IDE.Any open source or official plugin equivalent yFile for Rider IDE exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rider currently doesn't support UML diagrams out of box. While you can track issues regarding adding this feature [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-11582) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321) and hope for generosity of JetBrains, you can also use [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration).

It integrates PlantUML into almost all of the JetBrains IDEs. You can write your own descriptions of entities (in close to plain text style) from which UML will be generated.